# Let's abbreviate those numbers! Now reverse?

Tags: code-golf

**Introduction:**

Like Twitter and Instagram and others, I wanted to display numbers like `1.2K` and `3.8 M` instead of `1,222` or `3,823,456`.

But that's not all! As we all know, there might be some *human beings* which undoubtely won't like these abbreviations and will try to reverse them. So, `1.2k` will become `1,200` and `3.8 M` will become `3,800,000`.

**The task:**

- your task is to write a program or a function that converts a list of numbers (**which are given as strings**) into their abbreviate pairs and vice-versa.

For example, if the input list (or any `STDIN`) was `['1.4k', '1,234,567', '7.99M']`, then you should output:

```
['1,400', '1.2M', '7,990,000']
```

*You can follow the next schema for abbreviations:*

- 10<sup>3</sup> -> one kilo -> K
- 10<sup>6</sup> -> one million -> M
- 10<sup>9</sup> -> one billion -> B

Your code may assume all lowercase, all uppercase, mixed case or undefined case for input and use any of these for output, but should be consistent.

**Rules and restrictions:**

- you may write a program or function, taking input via `STDIN` (or closest alternative), command-line argument or function argument and outputting the result via `STDOUT` (or closest alternative), function return value or function (out) parameter.
- input may be in any convenient list or string format. You may assume that the `ai` are less than `231` each and that the list contains at least one element.
- each abbreviated number will contain **only one** `.` while a normal number will contain **as many** `,` **as necessary** (you may assume that this numbers won't be altered).
- you **MAY NOT** enter a number as `'123456'` but rather `123,456`
- standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply.

**Test cases:**

```
Input: ['1.5M', '77.6k', '123,456,789']         Output: ['1,500,000', '77,600', '123.4M']
Input: ['3,000,000,000', '581k', '2b']          Output: ['3B', '581,000', '2,000,000,000']
Input: ['0.1k']                                 Output: ['100']
Input: ['888', '33']                            Output: ['0.888k', '0.033k']
```

**Clarifications:**

- for numbers < 1000 after the decimal point in abbreviation output you should have as many digits as required to get the correct result. (e.g: `2` -> will become `0.002k`) - *that means 3 decimals at most*; for numbers > 1000 you can have *a maximum of 1 decimal*.
- the abbreviation may be in both lower or upper case
- **I removed the built-ins restriction as suggested in the comments**

The shortest code in bytes wins!

Comment: Requests for clarification: how many digits after the decimal point in abbreviation output? how to abbreviate numbers < 1000? uppercase or lowercase or both in input and output?

Comment: @edc65 I updated the test cases and added some clarifications

Comment: Shouldn't `'123,456,789' -> '123.4M'`? Also, this doesn't clarify how many decimals to use. Surely anything under 1000 shouldn't need to be abbreviated anyways.

Comment: @Shebang, yea' that `k` was a typo. Actually, I wanted to make it a bit interesting by adding the constraint of not keeping numbers < 1000 as they are. So, for those numbers, you may use 3 decimals at most, and for the rest, at most 1.

Comment: How far up do we have to support?  Up to the decillions, or what?

Comment: @anonymous2 read the third rule.

Comment: Can our output for numbers expanded from abbreviation have decimals? i.e. `1.5m -> 1,500,000.0`

Comment: @Shebang that would be a little confusing and it might be harder to read. Let's not allow it and keep our output clear ^_^

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but what is ai?

Comment: @anonymous2 `ai` is an element of the list / string or whatever `STDIN` you'd like to use.

Comment: According to `as many digits as required to get the correct result` , `888` should result in `0.888k`, not `0.8k`.

Comment: @Titus oopsie, missed that. Fixed :)

Comment: "you're not allowed to use any built-in module / function" *Any* built-in function?

Comment: @mbomb007 actually 2^31 stops at billions so that should be the limit. I removed the `so on` which was confusing.

Comment: The question disagrees with itself on whether the abbreviation for thousands is `k` or `K`, and whether the abbreviation for billions is `b` or `B`. It also fails to [specify the acceptable rounding modes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5608/194).

Comment: @PeterTaylor no, it doesn't. It might as well be `k` as much as `K`. As for the rounding modes, I didn't think it's required but I'll add it shortly ^_^

Comment: Your usage of "kilo" suggests SI prefixes and those would be `["k", "M", "G"]`. What does "while a normal number will contain as **many , as necessary**" mean, in my country it would be a mistake to use any.

Comment: @Angs People don't care if it's `k` or `K` when you're looking at Twitter. Most people aren't likely to think it's Kelvin.

Comment: Can the output be separated by newlines? For example: `"1,500,000\n 77,600\n123.4M"`

Comment: @KritixiLithos yes, that would be allowed

Comment: Also, shouldn't `['3,000,000,000', '581k', '2b']` be `['3,000,000,000', '581k', '2B'] `

Comment: @KritixiLithos It's just an example. The OP said case is not important. "It might as well be `k` as much as `K`." See the comments above.

Comment: I think that not allowing any builtin (for number-formatting, I guess) takes something from the challenge. As it is, you force everybody to one algorithm, and the language that can do that with the least overhead gets the cup. Removing that restriction will surely add more color to the answers and more to learn for the spectators.

Comment: @Titus ok, I removed that restriction! I hope everything is ok now as it is !

Comment: I made one more edit to prevent pennypicking questions; I think it doesn´t really matter (for the code) if the abbreviations are upper or lower case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## PHP, <s>234</s> <s>224</s> <s>213</s> <s>201</s> 205 bytes

```
for(;$x=$argv[++$n];){$y=str_replace(",","",$x)/1e3;for($i=0;$y>999;$i++)$y=($y|0)/1e3;echo(A<$c=substr($x,strlen($x)-1))?number_format($x*[k=>1e3,m=>1e6,b=>1e9][$c]):($i?($y*10|0)/10:$y).kmb[$i]," ";}
```

6 bytes saved by insertusernamehere, 4 bytes inspired by that.

---

- takes input from command line arguments, prints results space-separated with a trailing separator
- expects lower case abbreviation
- run with `-r`

-2 bytes if underscore as separator is ok: Replace `" "` with `_`.
-1 byte if correct rounding is ok: Replace `($y*10|0)/10` with `round($y,1)`.
-17 bytes for PHP 7.1: Replace `substr($x,strlen($x)-1)` with `$x[-1]`.

---

80 (63) bytes for expanding one argument only:

```
<?=number_format(($x=$argv[1])*[K=>1e3,M=>1e6,B=>1e9][substr($x,strlen($x)-1)]);
```

save to file, then execute (or replace `<?=` with `echo` +space and run with `-r`.

Comment: Your second example doesn't compile.

Comment: You have unbalanced parens.

Comment: @AlexHowansky oops that was the untested version. Fixed, thanks! Byte count was correct, however.

Comment: **-4 bytes:** `for($j=1;$x=$argv[$j++];)` – instead of `foreach($argv as$i=>$x)if($i)`

Comment: **-2 bytes:** `kmb[$i]` – instead of `"kmb"[$i]`.

Comment: **-10 bytes:** `$x[-1]>A` – instead of `ord(strrev($x))>57` (*PHP 7 only*)

Comment: @insertusernamehere Negative string indexes are coming in PHP 7.1; and that´s a RC (yet). Thanks for the other bytes!

Comment: You're right, sorry about that. And I actually thought this was a 7.0 feature. But I see, you could still use the approach anyhow. :)

Comment: Can't answer, but **05AB1E, 48 bytes** l'.¡`D'kåsD'måsD'bås¨Dl4-('0s×1@1@1@‚‚˜1k3*'0s×J

Comment: @Oliver It´s reopened; you can now turn your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 67 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
…KMBU3L3*°Vε',Ku¤©ai¨®XY‡*ïR3ô',ýRëY/ʒ1@N_~}ε4°z+N_·Ì.ò¨0Ü'.ÜXNè«}θ
```

What a mess.. :/

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcMyb1@nUGMfY61DG8LObVXX8S49tOTQysTMQysOrYuIfNSwUOvw@iDjw1vUdQ7vDTq8OlL/1CRDB7/4utpzW00ObajS9os/tP1wj97hTYdWGByeo653eE6E3@EVh1bXntvx/3@0kqGeqa@SjoKSubmeWTaIYWhkrGNiaqZjbmEJ4hrrGBgYwDBIwNTC0BtEGyWBSAM9Q7AuCwsLsGpjsBFAlbEA)

**Explanation:**

```python
…KMB                     # Push string "KMB"
    U                    # Pop and store it in variable `X`
3L                       # Push list [1,2,3]
  3*                     # Multiply each by 3: [3,6,9]
    °                    # Take 10 to the power each: [1000,1000000,1000000000]
     V                   # Pop and store it in variable `Y`
ε                        # Map over the (implicit) input-list:
 ',K                    '#  Remove all ","
    u                    #  Convert it to uppercase
 ¤                       #  Get the last character (without popping)
  ©                      #  Store this in variable `®` (without popping)
   ai                    #  If it's a letter:
     ¨                   #   Remove it from the string
      ®                  #   Push the letter from variable `®`
       XY‡               #   Transliterate it to the correct value in `Y` based on `X`
          *              #   Multiply the two numbers together
           ï             #   Cast it to an integer
     R                   #   Reverse it
      3ô                 #   Split it into parts of size 3
        ',ý             '#   Join it with "," delimiter
           R             #   Reverse it back
    ë                    #  Else:
     Y/                  #   Divide it by each value in list `Y`
       ʒ                 #   Filter this triplet by:
        1@               #    Check if it's >= 1
            ~            #    OR
          N_             #    The 0-based filter-index is 0
                         #    (so we'll still have a result left if <1000)
       }ε                #   After the filter: map over the remaining values:
         4°z+            #    Add 0.0001 to the number:
         4°              #     Push 10 to the power 4
           z             #     Divide 1 by this
            +            #     Add this 1/10000 to the number
         N               #    Push the 0-based map-index
          _              #    Check if it's 0 (1 if 0; 0 otherwise)
           ·             #    Double it (2 if 0; 0 otherwise)
            Ì            #    Increase by 2 (4 if 0; 2 otherwise)
             .ò          #    Round to that many decimals
               ¨         #    Remove the last digit
                0Ü       #    First trim potential trailing "0"
                '.Ü     '#    And then also trim a potential trailing "."
                   XNè«  #    Append the `N`'th letter of string `X`
        }θ               #   After the inner map: pop and leave the last item
                         # (after which the mapped list is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, <s>545</s> <s>524</s> <s>522</s> <s>518</s> <s>514</s> <s>508</s> <s>504</s> <s>498</s> <s>494</s> 214 bytes

Thanks to @ETHproductions for saving 180 bytes!

```
d=F=>F.map(f=>1/f.slice(-1)?f=(f=f.replace(/,/g,""))[9]?(f/1e8|0)/10+"B":f[6]?(f/1e5|0)/10+"M":f/1e3+"k":R(R(f.slice(0,-1)+"e"+' kMB'.indexOf(f.substr(-1))*3-0+"").match(/.{1,3}/g)+""),R=x=>[...x].reverse().join``)
```

To call the function:

```
d(["1.5M","1,500,000"]) //["1,500,500","1.5M"]
```

Outputs as `alert`, where each `alert` contains a different element of the input

Readable version:

```js
d = F => F.map(f => 1 / f.slice(-1) ? f = (f = f.replace(/,/g, ""))[9] ? (f / 1e8 | 0) / 10 + "B" : f[6] ? (f / 1e5 | 0) / 10 + "M" : f / 1e3 + "k" : R(R(f.slice(0, -1) + "e" + ' kMB'.indexOf(f.substr(-1)) * 3 - 0 + "").match(/.{1,3}/g) + ""), R = x => [...x].reverse().join ``)
```

**Summary of edits:** converted function to an arrow function

- removed semi-colons ';'
- removed `var`
- converted to an arrow function
- used map to iterate through the individual elements of the array
- used `|0` instead of floor
- used regex for testing
- used ternary operators instead of if-else statements
- included a separate function for `.reverse().join''`

Comment: [Here are some of the ways to golf this down.](https://github.com/ETHproductions/golf/blob/gh-pages/misc/98586.js) Feel free to ask any questions you might have :-)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), <s>322 321</s> 318 bytes

```python
import math
def f(l,r=[]):
 for s in l:
  if(c:=s[-1])in(p:=' kMB'):r+=[f'{int(float(s[:-1])*10**(p.index(c)*3)):,}']
  elif(i:=int(s.replace(',','')))>999:
   if(l:=math.log10(i))<4.5:r+=[f'{round(i/1e3,1)}k']
   elif l<7.5:r+=[f'{round(i/1e6,1)}M']
   else:r+=[f'{round(i/1e9,1)}B']
  else:r+=[f'{i/1e3}k']
 return r
```

-3 thanks to jezza_99

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bZExbsMgFIbVNadgg-cSGuLYiVGcIVuHnMDyYCXQIBNsYSK1qnKSLlnaO7WnqXGaVlUrhseTPr7_AS9v7ZPfN_Z8fj16NV583Kz0oW2cR4fK70c7qZAihrq8KEGMkGoc6pC2yPQN0opsRd4VY16CtqQVOUb1Zo1BuNu8UPhZW0-UaSpPukIEKuKTKCIt03YnH8kWohhA0BMue5s0vU-LPBzqmJOtqbaSYNovDACrLMtCaEg1Ig_jMdM88AnRAMsZS66hrjnaHdF3XMaUw6ke5IMdmeX8Py4N3ObKdfIvkQVi_TXmDzCEXBKc9Ednkbs84_t964bLkwJzNl1jinDMZptQE5bWoXI6jWffG5qk818NXWQTXAJchNf_-QQ)

Comment: [-3 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bZExbsMgFIbVNadgg-cSGuLYiVGcIVuHnMDyYCXQIBNsYSK1qnKSLlnaO7WnqXGaVlUrhseTPr7_AS9v7ZPfN_Z8fj16NV583Kz0oW2cR4fK70c7qZAihrq8KEGMkGoc6pC2yPQN0opsRd4VY16CtqQVOUb1Zo1BuNu8UPhZW0-UaSpPukIEKuKTKCIt03YnH8kWohhA0BMue5s0vU-LPBzqmJOtqbaSYNovDACrLMtCaEg1Ig_jMdM88AnRAMsZS66hrjnaHdF3XMaUw6ke5IMdmeX8Py4N3ObKdfIvkQVi_TXmDzCEXBKc9Ednkbs84_t964bLkwJzNl1jinDMZptQE5bWoXI6jWffG5qk818NXWQTXAJchNf_-QQ) by removing unnecessary whitespace

Answer (score 1):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), <s>207</s> 203 bytes

```python
lambda L:[s[-1]in'kMB'and f'{int(float(s[:-1])*10**(" kMB".index(s[-1])*3)):,}'or((i:=int(s.replace(',','')))>999>(j:=(i>1e6)+(i>1e9))and f'{(i/10**(j*3+2)+.5)//1/10}{"kMB"[j]}'or f'{i/1e3}k')for s in L]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XY9LboMwEIb3OQViMx7iGBuXp5Qssk5OQFmQBlSHFFCgUqsoJ-kmUtUepZueoLepDUSVKsua1z_zzbx9tq_9Y1Nf38vl_cdzXy6in-9j_rTb59YmSbt0ITJVQ7VdQ17vrRLOqu5JeWzynnRpoqvoCO44xLa0xmaq3hcvZGhDRyIm9ALNiRCVLE1jx05Fe8wfCgJUP0DEVRzHK3JIlkStRBHgfLAx4sQjyh0AB0fOPZwzH11X6NTlbBtiesgMYdjMFYW8VICljjtL1dYmm076ak_D3iQFwfwtUAvCkAWVcYQn6Z0f0DCK9UqScs5v35T9SAwyb62rnJkAoigyKSkhQ5zNxuG2nk39v8YwpMHoacIElYyvp6E3mfcfKEbDmaZUo8elrCCzcbzmeh3tLw)

Similar to @TheThonnu's [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/253716/110555) , but in a single line lambda and with sufficient differences that I feel it deserves a seperate answer

-4 bytes thanks to @97.100.97.109

Comment: [203 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XY9LboMwEIb3OQViMx7iGBuXp5Qssk5OQFmQBlSHFFCgUqsoJ-kmUtUepZueoLepDUSVKsua1z_zzbx9tq_9Y1Nf38vl_cdzXy6in-9j_rTb59YmSbt0ITJVQ7VdQ17vrRLOqu5JeWzynnRpoqvoCO44xLa0xmaq3hcvZGhDRyIm9ALNiRCVLE1jx05Fe8wfCgJUP0DEVRzHK3JIlkStRBHgfLAx4sQjyh0AB0fOPZwzH11X6NTlbBtiesgMYdjMFYW8VICljjtL1dYmm076ak_D3iQFwfwtUAvCkAWVcYQn6Z0f0DCK9UqScs5v35T9SAwyb62rnJkAoigyKSkhQ5zNxuG2nk39v8YwpMHoacIElYyvp6E3mfcfKEbDmaZUo8elrCCzcbzmeh3tLw)